# How to change format to a single cell in a SAS table

Tags: format, sas

I have to change format to a single cell in a `SAS` table. That is, the column where the cell is, has format `best12.`, while given that in the cell there is a date, for it I want to use `YYMMDD10.`

How can I fix?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What values are in the cells that don't contain dates?  It is possible to create a custom format to do what you want, but this will only work in certain situations, e.g. if there is no overlap between the date values and non-date values

Answer (score 0):

You can only associate a FORMAT with entire column.  If you want cells that have mixed type formatted differently you need a character column that put PUT (function) values into.

To associate a different format with a column use.

```
proc datasets;
   modify data-set-name;
   format variables new-format.;
   run;
   quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what you can do if the data allows.  Let's say that the earliest date in your data is 1st Jan 2000, this is stored as the number 14,610 in SAS (the number of days since 1st Jan 1960).  Therefore if no non-date values exceed this number then you can achieve your goal by formatting all values up to 14,610 as `best12.` and all values greater than this as `yymmdd10.`

```
proc format;
value dtfmt low - 14609 = [best12.]
                14610 - high = [yymmdd10.]
;
run;

data want;
input num;
format num dtfmt.;
datalines;
10
20
20514
30
;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `SUBSTR()` in `IF` condition to check for first character and format your variable accordingly..using `INPUT()` or `PUT()`